# making EditText not editable using if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I have to two EditTexts (editText1 and editText2 ) and I want the user to enter value inside editText1 first and then inside editText2, in another word I want to make editText2 not editable until the user enter something in editText1.

I tried but it didn't work:

```
   EditText editText1 ;
   EditText editText2 ;

    String Str1 = editText1 .getText().toString();

if(Str1.matches(""))
{
    editText2 .setKeyListener(null);    

}
```

Comment: Think you want to do editText2.setEnabled(false)

Comment: Do not forget to handle situation, when user write some text to editText1, then editText2 and after that he deletes text from editText1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might meet your requirements.

```
if(Str1.matches("")) {
    editText2.setEnabled(false);   

}else{
    editText2.setEnabled(true); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setEnabled()` method

```
if(Str1 == null || Str1.length() == 0)
{
    editText2.setEnabled(false);    
} else
{
    editText2.setEnabled(true);    
}
```

You should put that code into `OnKeyListener` for the first `EditText`. This will then enable and disable the second one based on the length of the text in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially do editText2.setEnabled(false) and then when the user types something in the first editText, you can do editText.setEnabled(true).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable any `view` element functionality using `.setEnabled(false)` method.

**So,** use

```
EditText.setEnabled(false);
```